# Please help me how to calculate function as shown below in C#

Tags: c#

```
    for (counter = 1;counter<=EncStr.Length;counter++)
    {
        switch (counter % 2)
        {
            case 0:
```

**This statement is being error**

```
                DecryptStr= DecryptStr +Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(EncStr.Substring(counter,1))-EncCode);
                break;
            default:
```

**This statement is being error**

```
                return DecryptStr+Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(EncStr.Substring(counter,1))+EncCode);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to explain what sort of error you get: doesn't it compile, do you get an exception, do you get a wrong answer? Please add any details that will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: no one can help you with the information you have provided

Answer (score 0):

The problem (i imagine) you face there is that you can't convert to char that int, this is how i would do it:

First DecryptStr must be a char array ->

```
char[] DecryptStr;
```

Then you have to conver the int to string and then char ->

```
DecryptStr = (Convert.ToInt32(EncStr.Substring(counter, 1)) + EncCode).ToString().ToCharArray();
```

The thing is now you cant do DecryptStr = DecryptStr + X; you will have to use a loop probably(since i do not know what you are doing there :S).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I need a decrypt from text file to make connection in sql database. Do uou have any solution, please share!